# script timed out before returning headers php 5.6 38 after apache upgrade

Tags: php, apache

I have updated apache version in my application to 2.4, as i am using PHP at front end. getting below error after upgrading the version-

> timeout waiting for output from cgi script /var/www/global-cgi-bin/php-5.6.38  script timed out before returning headers php 5.6 38

Comment: When you upgraded, did you compare the new apache config against your old apache config?

Comment: When I upgrade my Apache, I usually recompile my PHP to ensure all is well.  That is especially true if the path to Apache has changed.  I do this since I run `./configure --with-apxs2=<PATH TO APXS> ...`.  May not be required, that is just what I do.

Comment: yeah i compared there is no change in the apache config, rather the issue is intermittent.